# Should I put the article?

Tags: articles

I have the following passage:

> Prospects for the increasing of organic products sales volumes by
>   agrarian enterprises depend on the improvement of the marketing
>   product and assortment policy, (the) qualified pricing, (the) professional
>   logistics and distribution, and the formation of the manufacturer's
>   brand and its products.

I doubt about if I should use articles "the".

Comment: The definite article is not necessary here, but I would include it as it gives a nice parallelism to the elements in the list:  *the marketing product, the qualified pricing, the professional logistics, and the formation of ...*

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for help. You always give me a hand and clear answers.